# Default Document doesn't redirect

Tags: sharepoint-designer

My website's default document doesn't work.

I added default page on webconfig but my site doesn't redirect this page. It's going another site page. I tried to restart IIS and change new default document. But it didn't solved. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you go to Site Settings -> Under Look and Feel -> Welcome page, which page do you see here ?

Comment: Yes, it solved my problems. Thanks a lot @ArsalanAdamKhatri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to Site Settings -> Under Look and Feel -> Welcome page

Here you can give the URL to your site homepage

Answer (score 0):

open the site in designer, right click on the page you want to set as default page and select "set as default page"

Comment: I want to be my default page already default in designer, but it's not open.